# UPSERT query duplicates instead of overwriting

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to upsert a query. (Basically insert if nothing exists or update if there is a value already). **Postgres: 9.3.5**

This is my table:

```
box=> \d timeranges
Table "ana.timeranges"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 value  | text |
```

**I just want to update 'value' column.** (If an entry exists or create new entry)

I'm following this guide for writing upsert query:

> http://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/upsert/

This is my query:

```
WITH upsert AS (UPDATE timeranges SET value=value WHERE value='abc' RETURNING *) 
     INSERT INTO timeranges (value) SELECT 'abc' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);
```

**Second query:**

```
WITH upsert AS (UPDATE timeranges SET value=value WHERE value='abc3' RETURNING *) 
     INSERT INTO timeranges (value) SELECT 'abc3' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);
```

**Expected Result:**
There will be abc3 instead of abc1. (I want to overwrite it)

I don't understand what is wrong. When i change from 'abc' to 'abc2' **duplicate entry is created**.

```
box=> select * from timeranges;
 value 
-------
 abc
 abc3
(2 rows)
```

I thought it was supposed to overwrite it? I just want to overwrite previous entry

Please help me to fix where  I'm going wrong.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Both queries: `... SET value=value ...` something not obvious. Second query: `... WHERE value='abc3' ...` there is now entry for the `abc3` value after the first query, so the new entry was created, as expected.

Comment: So how do i modify the query so that I can just overwrite the new value? Instead of creating a new one?

Comment: `WITH upsert AS (UPDATE timeranges SET value='new-value' WHERE value='old-value' RETURNING *) 
     INSERT INTO timeranges (value) SELECT 'new-value' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Abelisto and SO: I fixed the query.

This is what i've used.

```
        WITH upsert AS (UPDATE timeranges SET value=? RETURNING *)
        INSERT INTO timeranges (value) SELECT ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert) RETURNING *;
```

This will update everything! or create one if it does not exist.